# importing a package from a subdir or relative path

Tags: python, package

Here's my directory setup:

```
mydir
├── script1.py
└── shared
    ├── otherstuff
    ├── script2.py
    └── pkg
        ├── box.py
        └── __init__.py
```

`script2.py` starts with

```
import pkg
```

and it works great. When I include the same line in `script1.py`, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pkg
```

Is there any good way to get syntax that simple to work in `script1.py`? I have been reading about `PYTHONPATH` and `sys.path` for the past hour, but I'm trying to make some basic functions available to my repo, and I can't believe that it will require modifying `PYTHONPATH` everytime I want to run a script.

What am I missing here? What's the best way to get `pkg` into `script1.py`?

Comment: Which version of python are you using 2.7? 3.x?

Comment: @Anthon, I'm using 3.x

Comment: Please show us the complete error. It seems as if a few lines are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do:

```
from shared import pkg
```

Also, your `shared` directory should have an `__init__.py` file

Comment: Its not a must , atleast not for python 3.x , didn;t test in python 2.x

Comment: Edited to reflect that!

Comment: Thanks @ssundarraj . That works. is there a way to do this in a `script3.py` that is in a different subdirectory of `mydir`?

Comment: Glad to help. Hope this answers your question.
`from ..shared import pkg` should work.

Comment: @ssundarraj hmm, that just gives me `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`

Answer (score 0):

I tested in python 3.x , You can do either -

```
import shared.pkg
```

or

```
from shared import pkg
```

Comment: Thanks @Anand Does this work without an `__init__.py` in the shared folder?

Comment: In my testing it did work without `__init__.py` in shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create the `__init__.py` file in `shared` and using `import shared.pkg`, you can work around this by doing:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'shared')

import pkg
```

Comment: Am I missing something here, I tried in python 3.4 similar directory structure, without a `__init__.py` in shared, and I am able to import `shared` , `shared.pkg`