# importing a local package without modifying sys.path

Tags: python, package

Here's my directory setup:

```
mydir
├── folder
    └── subfolder
        └── script1.py
└── shared
    ├── otherstuff
    ├── script2.py
    └── pkg
        ├── box.py
        └── __init__.py
```

`script2.py` starts with

```
import pkg
```

and it works fine. When I include the same line in `script1.py`, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pkg
ImportError: No module named 'pkg'
```

Is there any good way to get syntax that simple to work in `script1.py`? I am currently using `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('./shared'))` before `import pkg` (I'm calling `script1` from `mydir`), but that doesn't lend itself to easy repeated use, and it's clunky, and modifying `sys.path` is probably a bad idea in general.

What am I missing here? What's the best way to get `pkg` into `script1.py`?

Note: I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31019492/importing-a-package-from-a-subdir-or-relative-path/31019551#31019551) yesterday, but I didn't realize that the answers there wouldn't work for the dir structure above, which is what I actually need. Oops.

Python 3.x, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
sys.path.append('./../../shared/')
```

Strict limitations: This will only work if you plug it into `script1.py`, and if and only if `script1.py` remains in the `mydir/folder/subfolder` subdirectory.

Also, as far as I know, modifying `sys.path` is pretty much what you have to do in situations like this, so don't feel bad about doing it.